# simplexml_load_file generates same post repeatedly from WP feed

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I'm using `simplexml_load_file` to get rss feed from from a wordpress blog. Here is my code

```
$rssfile = simplexml_load_file( "http://blog.sufuraamathi.com/?feed=rss2" );
$items = $rssfile->channel->item ;

foreach( $items as $item ) {
  $article = array();
  $article['title'] = $item->title;
  $article['link'] = $item->link; 
  $article['category'] = $item->category;
}

foreach( $items as $item ) { ?>
 <?php if($article['category']=="Uncategorized") { ?>

    <div><?php echo $article['title'];?></div>
<?php
} } ;

?>
```

The Problem: It outputs the same post repeatedly x times, where x is total number of posts. Right now there are only two posts in the `Uncategorized` category and three more posts in other categories. But the code echos the following:

```
<div>Hello world!</div>
<div>Hello world!</div>
<div>Hello world!</div>
<div>Hello world!</div>
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on the fifth row of your posted code. You must take out the array definition of the first foreach loop:

```
$rssfile = simplexml_load_file( "http://blog.sufuraamathi.com/?feed=rss2" );
$items = $rssfile->channel->item ;

$article = array();  // <- put it here
foreach( $items as $item ) {
  $article['title'] = $item->title;
  $article['link'] = $item->link; 
  $article['category'] = $item->category;
}
...
```

as your current solution resets the `$article` array for each row. But why don't you loop everything in one foreach loop? If you're not using `$article` for some other purpose I don't see the use of assigning `$item` data to an array. Code could be simplified:

```
$rssfile = simplexml_load_file( "http://blog.sufuraamathi.com/?feed=rss2" );
$items = $rssfile->channel->item ;

foreach( $items as $item ) { ?>
 <?php if($item->category=="Uncategorized") { ?>
    <div><?php echo $item->title;?></div>
<?php
} } ?>
```